# Is there is any way to Read mapdb map from hdfs?

Tags: java, hdfs, mapdb

I want to access mapdb maps straight from HDFS, without copying it to local file system. Is it possible? Is there is any other approach by which I can read these maps without using local file system?

Comment: Since HDFS stores files in blocks, unless your file is smaller than the blocksize, you'll have to reconstruct the file somewhere in order to get your datafile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could read data into byte[], and then pass it to Store using VolumeFactory. However there is no public API for that yet. It is on my TODO list.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I was able to access mapdb over hdfs with just few hours of coding. I am not reading files in byte array as it can cause OOM, rather I am   reading files from hdfs.

Comment: @Akash_Mahajan How did you actually solve this issue? Are you also able to store changes back to Hdfs?

Comment: @Jan Kotek Can you explain how to use MapDB API to read byte[] etc ?